# Custom ViewModel Class - Not all fields are marked invalid unless a prefix is specified

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, data-annotations, xval

I have a custom viewmodel inside which I have two fields and one linq2sql entity .. all fields have Validation Attributes attached. Even if all fields are invalid only the fields in the linq2sql class are visually indicated for error and fields in the viewmodel are displayed normally. But the error messages are displayed for all invalid fields.

My Custom ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class BooksViewModel
{
    public SelectList BookCategories { get; set; }

    public Book Book { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Field1 is required")]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Field1 { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Field2 question is required")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

The Book class is a linq2sql entity which has a metadatatype attribute attached for validation.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(BookMetadata))]
public partial class Book
{
}
public class BookMetadata
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Choose a category")]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Published date is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage="Enter a valid date")]
    public DateTime PublishedDate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Author is required")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Author { get; set; }
}
```

There is a AddBook method in the repository with two overloads. One takes the viewmodel and one takes a Book type:

```
public void AddBook(Book book)
{
    var errors = DataAnnotationsValidationRunner.GetErrors(book);

    if (errors.Any()) {
        throw new RulesException(errors);
    }

    _db.Books.InsertOnSubmit(book);
    _db.SubmitChanges();
}

public void AddBook(BooksViewModel model)
{
    var errors = DataAnnotationsValidationRunner.GetErrors(model);

    if (errors.Any()) {
        throw new RulesException(errors);
    }
}
```

The Create action in the controller looks like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "Book.ID")]BooksViewModel booksViewModel)
{
    try {
        // Validate Book
        _repository.AddBook(booksViewModel.Book);
    } catch(RulesException ex) {
        ex.AddModelStateErrors(ModelState, "Book");
    }

    try {
        // Validate other fields in the view model
        _repository.AddBook(booksViewModel);
    } catch (RulesException ex) {
        ex.AddModelStateErrors(ModelState, "");
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    } else {
        booksViewModel.BookCategories = new SelectList(_repository.GetAllCategories().AsEnumerable(), "ID", "CategoryName", booksViewModel.Book.CategoryID);
        return (ActionResult)View(booksViewModel);
    }
}
```

I am using xVal to generate client side validation rules .. My create view looks like this:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="Book.CategoryID">CategoryID:</label>
            <%= Html.DropDownList("Book.CategoryID", Model.BookCategories, "Select")%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Book.CategoryID", "*")%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="Book.Title">Title:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("Book.Title")%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Book.Title", "*")%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="Book.PublishedDate">PublishedDate:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("Book.PublishedDate")%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Book.PublishedDate", "*")%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="Book.Author">Author:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("Book.Author")%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Book.Author", "*")%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="Field1">Field1:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("Field1")%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Field1", "*")%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="Field2">Field2:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("Field2")%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Field2", "*")%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

<% } %>

<div>
    <%=Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
</div>
<%= Html.ClientSideValidation<BooksViewModel>() %>
<%= Html.ClientSideValidation<Book>("Book") %>
```

the client side validation work fine .. but if I turn off javascript and then post back the form error message are displayed for all fields but the Field1 & Field2 are not marked as invalid .. there is no css class added to the fields and no span tags are generated for visual error indication.

[Screenshot http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/324/26677634.jpg](http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/324/26677634.jpg)

But if I pefix the ViewModel fields with anything

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Prefix = "VM", Exclude = "Book.ID")]BooksViewModel booksViewModel)
```

And modify the view accordingly then everything works fine:

```
<p>
    <label for="VM.Book.Title">Title:</label>
    <%= Html.TextBox("VM.Book.Title")%>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessage("VM.Book.Title", "*")%>
</p>

<p>
    <label for="VM.Field1">Field1:</label>
    <%= Html.TextBox("VM.Field1")%>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessage("VM.Field1", "*")%>
</p>

<%= Html.ClientSideValidation<BooksViewModel>("VM") %>
<%= Html.ClientSideValidation<Book>("Book") %>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Sorry for making this post so long ..

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be your variable name and class name are identical.

Perhaps in your ViewModel rename to something like,

```
public Book BookInstance { get; set; }
```

That'll require a bit of a refactor through, but I think it is the cause of your issue.

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: No changing the property name doesn't make any difference